# Altering a value between form submit and TryUpdateModel

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, webforms

I am probably missing something ready obvious. However, after trying to crack this all morning, I have gotten nowhere.

I am using Reverse Engineered Code First Entity Framework on my Web Form app.

I am attempting to update a submitted value before calling TryUpdateModel and can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my current code:

```
public void frmOrganisation_UpdateItem([RouteData] int id)
    {

        Website.Models.CrmOrganisation item = null;

        var query = from o in db.CrmOrganisations
                    where o.OrganisationId == id
                    select o;

        item = query.Single();

        if (item == null)
        {
            // The item wasn't found
            ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Item with id {0} was not found", id));
            return;
        }

        TryUpdateModel(item);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SaveChanges();

            Response.Redirect(Helper_Methods.AppendQueryStringToUrl("status", "Changes Saved!"));

        }
    }
```

One of the fields on the form is a textbox (id: txtWebsite) which is looking for a URL to be entered.  I will be storing the full URL (http:// included) in the databse. However, I don't want users to have to enter the http://. Therefore, I want to intercept the value submitted and, if it doesn't start http, I want to prefix it. Only then do I want TryUpdateModel (and therefore validation) to occur.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Chris.

**UPDATE - I've gotten alittle further.**

Between my "TryUpdateModel" and "if (ModelState.IsValid)", I now have the line "if (ModelState["Website"] != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ModelState["Website"].Value.RawValue.ToString())) ModelState["Website"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("http://" + ModelState["Website"].Value.RawValue, "http://" + ModelState["Website"].Value.RawValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);".

This is updating the model state, however, these changes are not being reflected in the database so I presume "db.SaveChanges();" is not seeing my change.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

I'm updating the fields according on the OnClick event of the button that then issues the command to the update method. So, use clicks button --> OnClick event fires and updates form --> UpdateItem method gets called and updates the model and database.